# How can I simplify the following Product of Sums: ab+ac'+a'b'+a'c+b'c'+bc?

Tags: logic

I started with POS: (a+b+c)(a+b'+c)(a'+b+c)(a'+b+c')

and after a long while, I got: ab+ac'+a'b'+a'c+b'c'+bc

and then I'm not sure how to simplify this. I thought maybe I can cancel the ab with a'b', and b'c' with bc and end with ac'+a'c but it doesn't seem to be right if I look at the truth table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** It turns out that your initial simplification was incorrect. Here's a correct one. First, observe that 
$$
(p+q)(p+q') = pp+pq'+pq+qq'=p +p(q'+q)+0 = p+p1=p
$$
so for the first two terms in your POS we have
$$
((a+c)+b)((a+c)+b') = a+c
$$
and, similarly, for the last two terms we have
$$
((a'+b)+c)((a'+b)+c') = a'+b
$$
so the full product simplifies to
$$
(a+c)(a'+b)\quad\text{ or, if you prefer }\quad ab+a'c+bc
$$
At this stage you haven't simplified this as much as possible. If you construct truth tables, you'll discover that $ab+a'c+bc=ab+a'c$, in other words the $bc$ term isn't needed here. It isn't obvious how one would discover that unless you've seen [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid simplification of your problem:

```
(b+c)(a+c)(a'+b)
```

I used Microsoft Z3 - http://rise4fun.com/Z3
with the following code:

```
(declare-const a Bool)
(declare-const b Bool)
(declare-const c Bool)
(assert (and (or a b c) (or a (not b) c)(or (not a) b c)(or (not a) b (not c))))
(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
```

I'm sure you could prove this equality using Natural Deduction or some other rules if you like.

`(a'c)+(ab)` is the shortest equivalent of that expression at the top of the answer.